# Proxy resource API in AWS api gateway returning last cached response for all all urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have enabled cache for one of the API configured in AWS API Gateway as per [resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html). The resource I created for this API are **Proxy Resource** as shown in image below -

[image]

Now the problem I am facing is for all urls same response (the one last cached) is returned, it does not matter if path are different. For example, ***/path/xyz*** and ***/path/xyz/p1*** return same response. I suspect that as this API is **proxy resource** (pass-through), the default cache keys are not unique and hence same response for all urls. Enabling request parameters for cache key wont help here.

Has anyone faced this issue? Or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working with the help of my colleague having expertise in AWS. It is simple and now I feel I should have given it try.

The answer to enable caching for those apis under resources as shown in image below -

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work for me for some reason. Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration which worked for me with proxy and solved the problem is with specifying every param I am using in template.yaml:

```
            paths:
              /{proxy+}:
                get:
                  security:
                  - api_key: []
                  parameters:
                    - name: param_one
                      in: query
                      type: string
                    - name: param_two
                      in: query
                      type: string
                   requestParameters: 
                      integration.request.querystring.param_one: method.request.querystring.param_one
                      integration.request.querystring.param_two: method.request.querystring.param_two
                    cacheKeyParameters:
                      - method.request.querystring.param_one
                      - method.request.querystring.param_two
```

Comment: where did you import this? it seems to only want swagger / json